# Keep track of laravel queued jobs

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I'm trying to get `department` details from an API which supports pagination, so if I spawn one job per page like following

```
/departments?id=1&page=1 -> job1
/departments?id=1page=2 -> job2
```

How can I keep track of these jobs for a particular department as I have to write the responses to `txt` file.

The jobs are instantiated via controller class like:

```
class ParseAllDeptsJob implements ShouldQueue
{
  public function handle()
  {
    foreach (Departments::all() as $dept) {
      ParseDeptJob::dispatch($dept);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to dispatch the job for a specific department when you visit a page?

Comment: @Mozammil let say yes, but the issue is not regarding dispatching jobs, like for a particular dept, i dispatch 5 jobs and at completion of these 5 jobs i have to send an email, now how can i know that those particular 5 jobs have finished processing successfully? does that clear things up a little bit?

Comment: I understand. I added an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can chain a job, using `withChain()`. This job will not run if the jobs higher up the chain fail.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues):

> Job chaining allows you to specify a list of queued jobs that should
>   be run in sequence. If one job in the sequence fails, the rest of the
>   jobs will not be run. To execute a queued job chain, you may use the
>   withChain method on any of your dispatchable jobs:

In your case, this is how you'd do it:

```
ParseAllDeptsJob::withChain([
    new SendEmailNotification
])->dispatch();
```

`SendEmailNotification` won't be dispatched if an error occurs while processing `ParseAllDeptsJob`.